# How to count the number of arrays in a nested array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to count the number of arrays in the nested arrays of an array

```
array = [[["-", 0, "I"], ["+", 0, "you"]], [["+", 3, "i"]], [["-", 4, "loved"], ["-", 5, "that"], ["+", 5, "it"], ["+", 6, "tasted"], ["+", 7, "like"]]]
```

This example would have 8 nested arrays inside the arrays in the `array` array. (not sure if I worded that right)

Comment: What do you want here? 8? You could use Regular Expression for that. I think it's the simplest way

Comment: `array.first.count` should do? @Desorder - could you explain how you would use RegularExpressions here?

Comment: @BroiSatse `array.first.count` and `array.first.size` gives 2.

Comment: Ah, there are two arrays, hard to spot those brackets. `array.flatten(1).count` will do.

Comment: @BroiSatse I need first to know if he's looking for 8 arrais (The most inner ones) or 11 (8 most inner ones plus 3 one level above)

Comment: That said, I'm not  Ruby guy so Ruby might have an easier way to solve this than Regex

Comment: @Desorder - Regex can be used for strings, how do you want to apply regex pattern to an array? Convert it to string first?

Comment: @Desorder 8 arrays (the most inner ones)

Comment: @BroiSatse That does the trick. Might want to make it an answer so i can give it to you. :)

Comment: @BroiSatse Sorry brother, I'm really embarrassed now... I copied the "array" and quickly scribed the Regex... It's a freaking array, Regex is not gonna do the trick... +_+

Comment: @user3234020: What should be the result for the array `[[[[],[],[]],[]]]` - should it be 1, or 2, or 3, or ....?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest/cleanest way is to partially flatten an array by one nesting level:

```
array.flatten(1).count
```

Other option is to sum sub-arrays:

```
array.inject([], :+).count
```

However the real question you need to ask to yourself is - how did I end up with such a weird construct?

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to properly state the question - I assume it to be count the number of arrays inside the nested array, which themselves do not contain another arrays.

```
def count_inner_arrays(arr)
  sub_arrays = arr.select { |el| el.is_a? Array }
  sub_arrays.empty? ? 1 : sub_arrays.map(&method(:count_inner_arrays)).inject(0, :+)
end
```